# DB2 String Tokenizer

Tags: function, stored-procedures, db2, db2-luw

I'm using a string tokenizer code as below - had it from my earlier question. It works fine without the QUALIFIER but soon as I add QUALIFIER KGT (schema name) to it - I get an error:

> THE CLAUSES ARE MUTUALLY EXCLUSIVE. SQLCODE=-628, SQLSTATE=42613,
>   DRIVER=4.17.36 SQL Code: -628, SQL State: 42613

```
    create function regexp_tokenize_number(
      source varchar(1000))
    returns table (tok integer)
    SPECIFIC regexp_tokenize_number
    LANGUAGE SQL
    QUALIFIER KGT
    DETERMINISTIC
    NO EXTERNAL ACTION
    return
    select tok
    from xmltable('for $id in tokenize($s,",") return <i>{string($id)}</i>' 
    passing cast(source as varchar(1000)) as "s"
    columns
      tok integer path 'if (. castable as xs:integer) then xs:integer(.) else ()'
    ) t
```

DB2 11 on Windows

Comment: Which operating-system runs your Db2-server?  (z/os, i-series,  linux/unix/windows) ?

Comment: @Ryan Please, provide a link to the DB2 documentation, where the `QUALIFIER` keyword is allowed to create an `SQL scalar` function.

Comment: DB2 11. Here it mentiones - For system naming, the function will be created in the schema that is specified by the qualifier. If no qualifier is specified:

If the value of the CURRENT SCHEMA special register is *LIBL, the function will be created in the current library (*CURLIB).
Otherwise, the function will be created in the current schema. https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/ssw_ibm_i_73/db2/rbafzcfsc.htm

Comment: That syntax (QUALIFIER) is only valid for Db2 for Z/OS in specific cases. It it not valid for i-series, or LUW.   When asking for help with Db2 you are wasting our time if you fail to specify your Db2-server platform. You can indicate the platform either in the text, or in the tags (there are specific tags for db2-400 (i-series) or db2-z/os, or dbw-luw.

Comment: @Ryan One more suggestion: if you work with one of 3 DB2s (`Db2 for LUW` in your case), then don't use documentation from another one (`DB2 for IBM i` as you provided in the comment above). Use the corresponding one: [CREATE FUNCTION (SQL scalar, table, or row)](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0003493.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DB2 for IBM i doesn't support such an XPATH syntax.
This works on Db2 for LUW, but not on DB2 for IBM i.

`QUALIFIER` keyword is not referenced as allowed in the `CREATE FUNCTION` statement on both these DB2 versions.